# JQuery setTimeout not working in a loop

Tags: jquery, settimeout

What I'm trying to do is create a quick and dirty slide show.  The idea being that I have master div containing a blank "master" img tag and set of divs, each containing it's own img and a span tag.  The source of each image is, in turn, set as the source of the master img.  So I had started iterating through each image and tried to set it's source the master img's source with a setTimeout() and a 2 sec delay.  The problem I'm having is that to code appears to wait for two seconds and only display the last image in the sequence.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#slideshow').children('div.slideshowsourceimage').each(function () {
        var src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        var desc = $(this).children('span').text();

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('img#slideshowimage').attr('src', src);
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

If I could get a second pair of eyes to help me find out what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciated it.

Thanks,

Comment: This probably occurs because you have overwritten `src` multiple times, by iterating through the children... or something like that. The `src` attribute seen by the timeout is not the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var $images = $('#slideshow div.slideshowsourceimage');
    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(x == $images.length) { // start over if we get to the last one
            x = 0;
        }

        var $cur = $images.eq(x);
        var src = $cur.find('img').attr('src');
        var desc = $cur.find('span').text();

        $('#slideshowimage').attr('src', src);
        x++;
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use setInterval or increment the number of seconds between each image showing.  What is happening now is everything is registered to occur in two seconds and so only the last image shows.  Something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var time=0;
    $('div#slideshow').children('div.slideshowsourceimage').each(function () {
        var src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        var desc = $(this).children('span').text();

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('img#slideshowimage').attr('src', src);
            time+=2000;
        }, time);
    });
});
```

Comment: This displays all at the same time for me.. just delays 2 seconds initially.